# XIB Links and Phone Numbers detection color

Tags: ios, hyperlink, xib, phone-number, detect

I find that auto detection of links and phone numbers in xib textfields is very useful,

is it possible to change the color of the autodetected link or number?

Answer (score 1):

In a UIWebView the detected data is just rendered as a link, so CSS will let you change that. In the UITextView, there isn't a method to make the change, so I would guess that you cannot. Additionally, you run afoul of the iOS GUI guidelines by making a link a color other than blue.

If you're dead set on changing the link colors then I would render your text in a UIWebView instead of a UITextView and use CSS. I wouldn't try to use UITextViews and private API's.